# FAQ Plug-in or Gem for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

FAQs seem to be a pretty commonly needed feature in a web application..
but it seems like there are no gems or plugins available for Rails.

Can you recommend a gem or plugin which provides FAQs to a Rails app?

Obviously you could make a simple FAQ very quickly with Rails, but there is much 
more functionality that can be added: votes, search, categories, roles, 
comments, markup, embedded links, tags, ... just to name a few.

Seems like people are re-inventing the wheel a lot for FAQs

Comment: obviously you could make a simple one very quickly, but there is much more functionality that can be added: votes, search, categories, roles, comments, ... to just name a few.   You could just as well argue that Authentication is an easy problem and you'd not need Devise. 

When it comes to FAQs it seems like everybody is just re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I think the problem with writing such a gem is that all of the extra functionality you mentioned would be better handled by gems and vanilla Rails features that already exist, so to write them again specifically for the FAQ gem would be re-inventing the wheel even more so than writing a custom FAQ feature each time you need one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just published a gem for it.

https://github.com/railscash/how_to

Hope that helps, Its in development phase but we are using it actively. Your comments/feedback will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think either using BrowserCMS (http://browsercms.org) or RefineryCMS (http://refinerycms.com/) fits the bill for when you need more generic content pages.  I prefer to just use a generic CMS instead of creating a gem/plugin for FAQS as you'll have other pages that could easily be thrown into a CMS engine as well.  Saves developer time from having to update mostly static HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely - Check out https://oraguide.com - Everything is streamlined / hosted in the cloud.  It runs directly on the page as a floating div.

[image: OraGuide - Website Help]